# Distributed Tracing logging and Integrating with Logstash,Kibana and ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have implemented a Distributed Transaction Logging library with Tree like Structure as mention in Google Dapper(http://research.google.com/pubs/pub36356.html) and eBay CAL Transaction Logging Framework(http://devopsdotcom.files.wordpress.com/2012/11/screen-shot-2012-11-11-at-10-06-39-am.png).

**Log Format**

```
TIMESTAMP   HOSTNAME  DATACENTER  ENVIRONMENT  EVENT_GUID PARENT_GUID TRACE_GUID APPLICATION_ID TREE_LEVEL TRANSACTION_TYPE TRANSACTION_NAME STATUS_CODE DURATION(in ms) PAYLOAD(key1=value2,key2=value2)
```

**GUID HEX NUMBER FORMAT**

```
MURMER_HASH(HOSTNAME + DATACENTER + ENVIRONMENT)-JVM_THREAD_ID-(TIME_STAMP+Atomic Counter)
```

What I would like to do is to integrate this format with Kibana UI and when user want to search and click on on TRACE_GUID it will show something similar to Distributed CALL graph which show where the time was spent.  Here is UI http://twitter.github.io/zipkin/.  This will be great.  I am not UI developer if some can point me how to do this that will be great.

Also I would like to know how I can index elastic search payload data so user specify some expression like in payload (duration > 1000) then, Elastic Search will bring all the loglines that satisfy condition. Also, I would like to index Payload as Name=Value pair so user can query  (key3=value2 or key4 = *exception*) some sort of regular expression.  Please let me know if this can be achieved.  Any help pointer would be great..

Thanks,
Bhavesh

Comment: Loading logs of that format through logstash into elatsicsearch would be easy.  Check out grok{}.  If you had the TRACE_GUID split out into a separate field, you would be able to search, browse, or filter on that value in kibana.

Comment: @AlainCollins,  Thanks for info.  Although, I can not use logstash and I have to use Apache Kafka for transport and costumer. And all logs do have TRACE_GUID propagated and indexed. Only thing is be able to customize the Kibana to display the call graph like zipkin.  I just wanted to feed JSON to Ziptkin UI and display that as one of Kinbana plugin.

Answer (score 1):

The first step to good searching in elasticsearch is to create fields from your data.  With logs, logstash is the proper tool.  The grok{} filter uses patterns (existing or user-defined regexps) to split the input into fields.

You would need to make sure that it was mapped to an integer (e.g. %{INT:duration:int} in your pattern).  You could then query elasticsearch for "duration:>1000" to get the results.

Elasticsearch uses the lucene query engine, so you can find sample queries based on that.

Comment: Thanks for help !! What is maximum amount of unique name value pair can you have ?  I have been ruining into problem with Name=Value pairs ? As # of unique name value pair increases it takes longer to index,  example, index for(int i  0-> 1million) index("key"+i,i) .

Comment: Next prob, is same key with different content type ? "key"="text value" and "key"=1 (int value), "key"=true ?  When indexing log line document with different content type for same field  how does it work ?  As far as I know index of dynamic infer and (first one wins ) ?  Please let me know the behavior.

Comment: We have an index with 7,000+ fields, so I can't comment on 1M.

Comment: Fields get a mapping, which is fixed for the index.  They can be string, int, etc.  If you insert an int into a string, it will cast it.  Obviously, you can't insert a string into an int field.